# app store 'digital' points purchasing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is it is possible to make users pay for digital points so that they can use them for real-world services outside of the app?

Take for example 'Uber', assuming we have the same model, can users purchase 'bundles' of 'points' and then use these points to order a taxi service?

Will this be allowed on the app store?

Comment: See [Purchasing and Currencies](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) section of the _App Store Review Guidelines._

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the "digital wallet" problem. All kinds of issues exist, from security, to convincing vendors to accept it, to convincing customers to trust and use it, to figuring out how you're going to take a fair profit out of it..

Frankly, Apple has claimed to be working in this space themselves, as are the credit card companies. Given your question, I have to assume you have nowhere near the resources they can afford to spend on this effort, and their efforts are still vaporware.

If you really have a way to make this work, I suspect you could sell it to one of them for a few million. If you just have the idea... well, it's premature to try to guess whether Apple would try to lock you out or not, and only they can answer that question in any case.